# Why does Community User on Area 51 have random profile picture?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, community-user, profile-picture

[Community User of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1/) has a random profile picture.

[image]

Can we update it's profile picture with our [standard profile picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)?

---

**Edit:** The community user got a random profile picture again.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean community has an email address for gravatar to work? If I can just reverse engineer this I'll be able to find the community email andress and send all the emails I want to team@stackexchange.com, **ah haha ha ha ha"**.... O, wait, yeah

Comment: Strangely enough, we also have another [Community](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/94921/community) user. Not sure what went wrong here.

Comment: @Oded - That one is not a community user IMO. Since his userid is not -1

Comment: But how did it get its diamond? It can't just be someone pretending to be community

Comment: @RichardTingle - That _is_ the community user. Not sure what is going on though. Still looking into it.

Comment: @RichardTingle - Indeed. It has [Gravatar picture](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7876e382e5c12dfe547c35c64fd05f5b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG).

Comment: @Oded [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/94921/community) is a fake, most likely someone made it for fun and now laughing his a$$ off.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it _is_ fake. Has an email attached to it and was done for lolz (a familiar email, at that).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - no he doesn't

Comment: @Oded probably cache, you're right! Any hint who it was? :-D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not telling.

Comment: Nothing fixed. Why is it status-completed?

Comment: @nicael - It *was* fixed but it is changed again.

Comment: So it *wasn't* fixed

Comment: [No repro here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQ3T.png) (unless Oded fixed it again without telling us :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard - He has just fixed.

Comment: Oh wait, it got the default identicon on the [Discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) - @Oded FYI

Comment: @ShadowWizard - thanks. I asked someone with Mod powers there to fix both.

Comment: @Oded but as a dev can't you give yourself a diamond? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - sure, I **can**. But do I want to?

Comment: @Oded it's shiny. It's powerful. Why not? Oh, wait... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All sorted, thanks to @TimPost.

Community user is back to its old self, all impostors destroyed.

Comment: What happened? The email value  was different on Area51 somehow?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it was.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it was `mail.to.oded.funniest.area51.proposals@gmail.com`

Comment: @gnat [nope](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d9a1d452d5a86d64a5910538beeb356b.jpg) ;) (generated using [this tool](http://asaph.org/gravatar/))

Comment: Nothing fixed!!!

Comment: @nicael - you mean it broke again.

Comment: Question is, what keeps breaking it? Any juicy details?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - no idea, yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - It seems the Area51 is out of control.

Comment: @hims056 - it must be Community user itself. See what he did yesterday...

Comment: @Oded He's become sentient.

Comment: @Oded so you're the true creator of the [Technocore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technocore)... wow! :D